# Where can I see the local tax rates on capital gains?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax

Capital gains are taxed at 3 levels in the United States: [federal](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Capital_gains_tax_in_the_United_States&oldid=992180142#Current_law), state and local. (to which one might have to add the  [Net Investment Income Tax (NIIT)](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/questions-and-answers-on-the-net-investment-income-tax#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20Net%20Investment,above%20the%20statutory%20threshold%20amounts.) if one's income is higher than some threshold.)

https://smartasset.com/investing/capital-gains-tax-calculator:

[image]

I'm curious to see the typical local tax rate on capital gains. Where can I see the local tax rates on capital gains? https://smartasset.com/investing/capital-gains-tax-calculator only allows to enter 1 location at the time, whereas I'd like to see an overview for the entire US (or at least one entire state).

---

For example, for state  rates on capital gains, https://www.fool.com/taxes/2014/10/04/the-states-with-the-highest-capital-gains-tax-rate.aspx ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205000240/https://www.fool.com/taxes/2014/10/04/the-states-with-the-highest-capital-gains-tax-rate.aspx)) gives a nice synopsis:

[image]

complemented by https://www.cbpp.org/research/state-budget-and-tax/state-taxes-on-capital-gains ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205000223/https://www.cbpp.org/research/state-budget-and-tax/state-taxes-on-capital-gains)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I imagine most local capital gains tax rates are equivalent to local income tax rates, for which I have found [this article](https://taxfoundation.org/local-income-taxes-2019/) by the Tax Foundation to be the best summary. Here is their map:
[image: Local Income Tax Collections]

Of course if you're really considering an area you'll have to look into it further to determine what exactly you'd pay and how/if it applies to capital gains. But this should give you a pretty good idea to get started, and also let you know what areas of the country you probably won't face any local income taxes.

Comment: Why the downvote? If the answer contains incorrect information, please let us know.